# Laravel only "home page" route working on live server

Tags: laravel, apache, url, server

I need help with URLs on the server...

this is my example:

10.10.10.50/projectname/ -- work 
10.10.10.50/login - don't work

10.10.10.50/**projectname**/login - work

The main problem is, if I click something on the page, for example, ‘login’ it’s directed 10.10.10.50/login, instead of 10.10.10.50/projectname/login

In httpd.conf file i allowoverrired all:

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

this is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>     Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public// [L,NC]
</IfModule
```

Thanks

Comment: > it’s directed 10.10.10.50/login, instead of 10.10.10.50/projectname/login 
Did you specified your APP_URL correctly in the .env file? Should be `http://10.10.10.50/projectname` if you run your app in a sub folder.

Comment: @Kovah yes, I am... problem is in "a href links" in app... example: `<a href="/login">`  they don't work, and in case `<a href="login">`  work...I look in scripts where I can make the right path for all links suddenly... ?

Comment: if you want them to redirect to projectname/login, you can specify it in your web.php file where all the routes are defined.

Comment: How should links like `<a href="/login">` automatically redirect to `<a href="/projectname/login">` if you do not specify any rewrite rules for that? And why don't you use `<a href="{{ url('login') }}">`?

Comment: @Kovah thanks for your answer. I replaced "login" with ```<a href="{{ url('login') }}">``` The problem is that I was finished this project on localhost on my computer but this version is on remote server. And now every link is wrong... example: I have something like this: ```a href= "/tasks/{{$task->id}}">{{$task->naziv_zadatka}}</a>``` and in this case now missing name of root folder or aplication on click..  App goes to ```10.10.10.50/tasks``` instead ```10.10.10.50/project/tasks```... it's not problem for one, but I have more than fifty links